# How to make a remote server call from a react component?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

The thing is: I have a small react app and remote server (only url is known). Also, I know some of server methods, for example "GET /api/records" - to get all data from the server. How to communicate through this method?

I have a button, which starts a handler, where I use fetch.

```js
getRecords() {
    fetch("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000/api/records/", {method: "GET"})
        .then((response) => console.log(response));
}
```

By the console.log, I receive a Response object. How can I get data from it?

Comment: Check this out: http://www.techcuriosity.net/working-with-vue-js-and-asp-net-web-api-2/ This tutorial is for Vue.js but will work in similar way. You'll be working in componentDidMount method in react instead of mounted from vue

Answer (score 1):

From the handler you can hydrate your state with the response. Try:

```
getRecords() {
    fetch("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000/api/records/", {method: "GET"})
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
             this.setState({
                 yourDataKey: data
             })
        })
}
```

From [Google documentation:](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch)

> The response of a fetch() request is a Stream object, which means that when we call the json() method, a Promise is returned since the reading of the stream will happen asynchronously.

So, the first then will convert the stream object to json, and the second then will save the json on the component state.

Comment: thank you, it seems to me I do something wrong. It's test task for my first job. When I request something, I only get strange object, but the row for table is expected. Maybe you could gime me a piece of advice, what I should read to perform communication with a backend? In google there are a lot of information, so I can't pick what fit in my place.

Comment: I understand and hope to be helpfull. You need to better understand the React Components lifecycle (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) and how state gets rendered when updated. You can find all the answers in the official docs, for the api calls I believe this will help: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html. Good luck